# I/O Device Error while trying to Turn On BitLocker

Tags: windows-8, encryption, bitlocker

I'm trying to turn on BitLocker on a 1TB drive in an MSI GS70 laptop running Windows 8 Pro.

As soon as I click "Turn On BitLocker", the first step of the wizard shows the following error:

```
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
```

I've already gone through the steps of allowing BitLocker without a TPM, and attempting to enable it on other devices (an external USB drive in this case) works fine.

No events appear in Event Viewer while doing this, and the drive is otherwise running fine.

What other things could I look for in trying to get BitLocker working, or is there any way to get a more detailed error message?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of this?  I'm having the same issue and can't find any error logs to discern the true cause, and it's very frustrating for me.

Comment: @MauriceReeves Alas, no, I never did find a cause of this. It's _possible_ that it's because I have my Users folder hardlinked to another drive, but I haven't had the chance to reformat my machine to test that theory.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is too late, but I think I have found a solution to this (at least on my machine it worked after this fix) -- 
It is related to the firmware of the SSD not the SSD itself, so after updating to the newest version of the firmware and restarting it, bitlocker magically work :)